# FTP server keeps stopping (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, ftp

On a MacPro at remote office, I enabled FTP server with

```
sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

Now it works, but when downloading a large file, it will serve for a few seconds, then stop completely for a minute or more ... then resume (using `lftp` with multiple connections.)

Like this:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? Or is there a more reliable FTP server service we could use?

`brew search ftp` shows me

```
bbftp-client   git-ftp        ncftp      pure-ftpd      vsftpd
curlftpfs      lftp           proftpd    uberftp
```

Are any of these FTP servers that could be set up as an always-on 'service'?

UPDATE: I installed pure-ftpd, got it up and running, and it's doing the same damn thing. 34mbps for 10 seconds, then 0 for 30 or so ... what is going on?

Comment: Might it be your connection that is failing, are you on WiFi? Have you tried to do this via AFP, SMB, or the webserver?

Comment: You can go to 'System preferences' -> 'Sharing' -> 'File Sharing', that should start your FTP server. And there you can also activate SMB and AFP under options. No need for calling `launchctl` manually.

Comment: AFAIK, Apple removed the FTP option in Mavericks. I don't see it. The only way I know to start it is via `launchctl`. AFP transfer maintains, but speeds are only 5-10mbps. Maybe going through LogMeIn Hamachi VPN is affecting it. I will have to test a direct connection.

Comment: You might try  'System preferences' -> 'Sharing' -> 'Remote Login' for a SFTP server.

Comment: → Ze'ev: is Wi-Fi involved there (CousinCocaine ®)?

Comment: @danielAzuelos no, no wifi, just gigE.

Comment: @CousinCocaine I need FTP for my clients

Comment: Also ... I tried testing with `iperf -c 25.1.203.32 -r -l 100M` and fastest I got was around 11mbps. Speedtest.net says our upstream is around 70mbps. Tried iperf with a public server, and got 52mbps

Comment: This doesn't fit with GE. Run `mtr target_ftp_server` from your client and analyze your network bottleneck.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Sorry, what is "GE"? And what is `mtr`? I don't have that installed. update: ok, i see it in brew, installing.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Installed mtr ... now what? It's showing 0% loss. Can it show speed?

Comment: @Ze'ev, I understand you want FTP, but I am trying to help you debugging, testing other protocols might give us a clue. I think your FTP server is fine but your connection is not. 'Speedtest.net' measures speed between your providers hub and a server and is not reliable in my opinion.

Comment: GE == Gigabit Ethernet.

Comment: → Ze'ev: from the information thus far, you don't have an `ftp` problem, but a basic `network` problem.
You should edit this question to fix the subject. Then you'll get skilled colleagues to read your question and propose you different levels of answer suited to the *right* question.

Comment: @danielAzuelos - I tested our connection using `iperf` to a public iperf server and got 50-70 mbps upload... doesn't that mean the network is fine, and that it's a software issue?

Comment: Software issue is highly unlikely. Have you tried other protocols? (SMB, SFTP, AFP, etc)

Comment: is this a duplicate post? http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/141713/55028

Comment: → Ze'ev: no this isn't a correct method for trouble shooting a network problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could you test your end to end connection with this simple script based on `ping` output:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: coupure.sh,v 1.1 2012/09/05 13:11:10 dan Exp dan $
_host_exist=`host $1`
expr "${_host_exist}" : '.*address' >/dev/null || {
        echo ${_host_exist} >&2
        exit 1
}

ping $1 2>/dev/null |
        perl -e  '
                use strict ;
                use warnings ;

                my $started = 0 ;
                my $start = 0 ;
                my $end = 0 ;
                my $count = 0 ;
                my $was_down = -1 ;
                my $last_up = -1 ;
                my $last_hole = 0 ;
                my $now = 0 ;
                my $x = -1 ;
                my $hour = -1 ;
                my $min = -1 ;
                my $sec = -1 ;
                my $hole = 0 ;
                my $delta = 0 ;
                my $time_run = 0 ;
                my $sum_hole = 0 ;
                my $avg_hole = 0 ;
                my $sum_delta = 0 ;
                my $avg_delta = 0 ;

                sub catch_int {
                        $end = time () ;
                        $time_run = $end - $start ;
                        printf ("\ntime run = %14d s,\tdrop count =  %8d", $time_run, $count) ;
                        if ($time_run) {
                                printf (",\t %8.2f / d\n", $count * 86400 / $time_run) ;
                        } else {
                                printf ("\n") ;
                        }
                        if ($count) {
                                $avg_hole = $sum_hole / $count ;
                                printf ("avg drop time =  %8.2f s\n", $avg_hole) ;
                                if ($count > 1) {
                                        $avg_delta = $sum_delta / ($count - 1); 
                                        printf ("avg int. time =  %8.2f s\n", $avg_delta) ;
                                }
                        }
                        exit ;
                }

                $start = time () ;

                $SIG{INT} = \&catch_int ;

                while () {
#                       printf ("%s", $_) ;

                        if (! $started) {
#                               printf ("%s", $_) ;
                                if ($_ =~ /PING/ ) { next ; }
                                if ($_ =~ /bytes/) {
                                        $was_down = 0 ;
                                } else {
                                        $was_down = 1 ;
                                }
                                $started = 1 ;
                        } else {
                                if ($_ =~ /bytes.*icmp_seq=/) {
#-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#                                       target is up
#                                       printf ("!") ;
                                        if ($was_down == 1) {

                                                $count ++ ;
                                                printf ("%4d\t", $count) ;
                                                ($sec, $min, $hour, $x, $x, $x, $x, $x, $x) = localtime ($last_up) ;
                                                printf ("%02d:%02d:%02d\t", $hour, $min, $sec) ;
                                                $now = time () - 1 ;
                                                ($sec, $min, $hour, $x, $x, $x, $x, $x, $x) = localtime ($now) ;

                                                printf ("-\t%02d:%02d:%02d\t", $hour, $min, $sec) ;
                                                $was_down = 0 ;
                                                $hole = $now - $last_up ;
                                                $sum_hole += $hole ;
                                                printf ("= %4d s", $hole) ;

                                                if ($last_hole) {
                                                        $delta = $last_up - $last_hole ;
                                                        $sum_delta += $delta ;
                                                        printf (" + %6d s\n", $delta ) ;
                                                } else {
                                                        printf ("\n") ;
                                                }
                                                $last_hole = $last_up ;
                                        }
                                        $last_up = time() ;
                                } else {
#-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#                                       target is down
                                        if ($was_down == 0 ) {
                                                $was_down = 1 ;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }'
```

Just copy this in `coupure.sh` on your ftp client,
type `make coupure` and run it:

```
./coupure target_ftp_server
```

Comment: I tried `./coupure 25.14.33.139` and it said `Host 139.33.14.25.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)` ... seems to be reversing the IP addres??

Comment: Yes. That was my only way to check that a name was valid even when `ping` wasn't answering at first. You might remove the block starting at `expr` if you don't want to register your ftp server.